# Signal is virtual warning

Tags: qt5, signals, compiler-warnings

I am writing a Qt5/C++ app and the base class defines a signal, to be overridden by descendants.

The Qt IDE shows a warning on the header where I define the signal:

```
Signal is virtual [clazy-virtual-signal]
```

I don't understand the warning.  I know the signal is virtual...why is that a problem

Comment: What do you mean by `"... class defines a signal, to be overridden by descendants"`?  The definition of a signal is generated by `moc` so making it `virtual` is redundant, right?

Comment: I didn't realize that.  I assumed that since my descendants will override I had make it virtual.  So are you saying the MOC will change it to be virtual, so the warning is that my virtual word is redundant?

Comment: Again, what would it mean to `override` a signal?  When you write a call such as `emit some_signal()` is simply triggers the `moc` generated code that checks/calls the slots to which `some_single` has been connected.  The class/type specific (i.e. `polymorphic`) behaviour is defined by the receiving slots -- *not* the signal.

Comment: I'm having trouble drawing a recommendation out of your comment.  So are you saying one should not define a signal in a base class, only in the descendant that uses it?  But what if a base class method uses the signal as well?

Comment: I'm not 'recommending' anything as such.  Simply pointing out that declaring the signal to be virtual won't achieve anything.  As an exercise, write up a simple [mcve] that has a virtual signal in the base class that is overridden in a derived class and explain how you will use it and what you think it will do.